# Delete all (keys, value and data) from Register with batch

Tags: batch-file

how can i delete keys, value and data, of a name in the same time, from Register with batch file?
For example: the name that i want delete is "vlc"
How can i delete in the same time, keys, value and data (so all) from register, with a batch file?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try the reg.exe command...

reg delete /f HKLM\Software\Subkey\Subkey